# Foundation Overlapping Responsive Images

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

This is essentially what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I have an image I want to use as the background for the webpage, and I want to put content over it, while **keeping everything responsive so it's always centered!**. I'm using Foundation 4, which is making things tricky (but I want to learn how to do it this way). The black boxes will be images, and the idea behind this is that everything can remain responsive.

The black boxes are supposed to be centered. I've tried using absolute positioning for the boxes and forgoing trying to put them in a , but it doesn't seem to work too well (i could be doing something wrong).

Overlapping anything in Foundation 4 seems tough. I must be going about it wrong somehow. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to check your HTML code structure to confirm but I think what you want is `.small-centered` and `.large-centered` (they work the same as `.small-1`,`.large-1` but for centering).

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html (Search for **Centered Columns** on page).

Also for the boxes I hope you are using Foundation's **Block-Grid** for your boxes - it will make your boxing a lot easier to do.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block-grid.html